# detecting the side of a cube that is facing the camera in android opengl es

Tags: android, opengl-es, cubes

So I started creating an app to learn openGL es on adroid. First I went through a chapter that explained how to construct a cube and get it to rotate using the system timer. I then mapped each side to a different segment of one image. For development purposes each side is textured with a number. I then implemented the drag feature to allow the user to rotate the cube up/down or left/right depending how they swiped.

First here is some background on my problem:

I want to keep track of which side is facing the camera because each face is being rotated on the axis it started on. For example given a cube that has the unfolded layout as follows.

```
  2
  4
3 1 5
  6
```

Where 1 is the side facing the screen, 2 is the opposite (or back face), 4 is up, 5 is right, 6 is down, and 3 is left.This means 3/5 are on the x-axis, 4/6 on the y-axis, and 1/2 on the z axis.

Here is my issue:

The cube rotates correctly if I only rotate around 1 axis (i.e. I only go left/righ or up/down until I go 360) but if I only go to 90 180 or 270 then the axis I should be rotating around have switched. This happens because of what is stated above about each side of the cube being stuck to the axis it started on.

If you rotate right once so 5 is facing, then the z axis from the users perspective is the x-axis of the cube. This gets even more convoluted when you start going 90 degrees left/right then 90 degrees up/down, etc.

I tried to keep track of the faces with an array of numbers listed clockwise from the top number, but depending which number you came from the new directions for the surrounding numbers have changed.

For Example:

I mapped out the numbers surrounding each number as it faces the screen if it was rotated to from 1 so

```
  4         2         4         1         4           
3 1 5     3 4 5     1 5 2     3 6 5     2 3 1     
  6         1         6         2         6
```

and 2 is a wild card because it can be gotten to from any direction so there is no real initial number layout from 1

```
  6  
3 2 5
  4
```

So my arrays would be

```
sidesOfFace1[] = {4,5,6,3}
sidesOfFace2[] = {6,5,4,3}
sidesOfFace3[] = {4,1,6,2}
sidesOfFace4[] = {2,5,1,3}
sidesOfFace5[] = {4,2,6,1}
sidesOfFace6[] = {1,5,2,3}
```

And MOVE can have the values

```
UP = 1  RIGHT = 2  DOWN = 3  LEFT = 4
```

Then by keeping track of the previous face, curr face, and last move I tried to figure out a formula to get an offset that would help me select what the next face would be given a direction to move to a new face. Roughly I came out with this interpretation:

```
prevface MOVE currFace
    1 -> UP(1) -> 4 -> RIGHT(2) -> 5

offset = opposite direction of MOVE - (sidesOfFace.indexOf(prevFace)+1)

So first I get
   1) DOWN - sidesOfFace4.indexOf(1)+1 => 3 - 3 = 0

   2) LEFT - sidesOfFace5.indexOf(4)+1 => 4 - 1 = 3
```

1) This tells me that the sides around 4 are in the same order as the array sidesOfFace, in clockwise starting at the top. So when the user swipes again I can know which side we are going to. This is imperative in being able to set up the right rotations of the cube since they change for the viewer as the cube gets turned.

2) This shows that there is an offset, if we look at the array the index of 4 should be 0 but the cube has been rotated such that the UP side is now at index 3, RIGHT is 0, DOWN is 1, and LEFT is 2.

Besides needing to know which side is facing the screen for other functionality in my app, I also have to know because depending on which side is facing the screen I have to rotate the cube along the correct axis. I am keeping track of the xRot and yRot but these rotations have to happen according the the camera/users view, not the cubes axis.

For Example I found that:

```
axis for front face  up/down axis  right/left axis  (as seen by the camera)
    1   +z              +x             +y
    2   -z              -x             -y

    4   +y              +x             +z
    6   -y              -x             -z

    5   +x              +z             +y
    3   -x              -z             -y
```

This means that depending on which side is facing the screen I have to do the xRotations around the up/down axis and the yRotations around the right/left axis.

A friend said something about possibly checking the 4 vertices that are closest to the camera but since I am using glRotate funcs I wasn't sure where I could get that information from. But I still need to know which numbers are on which side of the front face so I can automate the rotations of the cube.

If you actually sat down and read all this I truely do appreciate it, If you could steer me in the right direction. Maybe a link, or better yet a known solution to this problem would be amazing. I have been struggling with this for a few days now and I was just wondering if this was already a problem that had a solution.

Thanks all,

Alan

Answer (score 1):

I'll be honest I didn't completely read the last 3/4 of your post, it's looking way more complicated than it needs to be.

But if you just want to detect which side of the cube is nearest the camera, you should just have to do the following:

With your unrotated cube, create a vector for each direction:

```
vec3 left(-1, 0, 0)
vec3 right (1, 0, 0)
vec3 up(0, 1, 0)
etc...
```

Then acquire the current modelview matrix of the cube. If you transform the normal by the cube's modelview, you will get the resulting vectors in eye space.

```
vec3 leftInEyeSpace = modelView * left;
vec3 upInEyeSpace = modelView * up;
...
```

This will be the direction of each vector relative to your eye.

Then define a vector from the center of the cube pointing into the camera:

```
vec3 cubeToCamera= -normalize((modelView * vec4(0,0,0,1)).xyz);
```

Then you want to take the dot product of each vector with your 'cubeToCamera' vector. Because the dot product decreases as the angle between the vectors increases, the dot product with the greatest magnitude will be the one most facing the camera.

```
float leftDot = dot(cubeToCamera, leftInEyeSpace)
float rightDot = dot(cubeToCamera, rightInEyeSpace)
...
```

Comment: I'll look further into this. My biggest issue is I am trying to automate it so I can have an input of sides, and there will be an easy way to display each side in order. To do this I have to know which way to turn for each side, regardless of which number it came from. This is why the description was so long, and seems convoluted.

Your solution works for finding which face is currently facing the screen, but I also need to figure out which sides are in each direction (in correlation to the front facing side). Is there a reliable way figure out which way the other vectors are pointing ?

Comment: *Is there a reliable way figure out which way the other vectors are pointing ?* It should be pretty easy I think. You already have the six eye-space direction vectors (in my example as 'leftInEyeSpace', etc). So by just looking at these vectors you can tell which way each side is facing. Similar to how you can see which side is facing the camera, you can also compare these vectors to other directions. If after transform, the 'top' vector is close to (1,0,0), then you know it is pointing rightward. @AlanDeLonga

Comment: @AlanDeLonga : Also I realize this is a bit different a solution than you were originally going for, I originally assumed that this was a fully 3D cube with arbitrary rotation on all axises, and with an arbitrary camera position. If you're locking the cube to only one of six directions, with a static axis aligned camera, then this might be a more convoluted solution than you need. However I think this is the 'proper' way to do something like this in full 3D, and it should work for you in any case.

Answer (score 0):

A bit convoluted, but could something like this work? I left out a few methods but hopefully you get my general idea, you should be able to use the boolean variables to work out which side is facing the user.

```
private Boolean right, left, spin;
private Boolean up, down, upsideDown;
private Boolean rightSide, leftSide;
// All false by default.

public void swipe(int swipeDirection)
{
    // Swipe Direction - 0 = Right, 1 = Left, 2 = Up, 3 = Down
    switch (swipeDirection)
    {
    case 0:
        if (upsideDown)
        {
            swipeLeft();
        }
        else if (rightSide)
        {
            swipeDown();
        }
        else if (leftSide)
        {
            swipeUp();
        }
        else
        {
            swipeRight();
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        if (upsideDown)
        {
            swipeRight();
        }
        else if (rightSide)
        {
            swipeUp();
        }
        else if (leftSide)
        {
            swipeDown();
        }
        else
        {
            swipeLeft();
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        if (upsideDown)
        {
            swipeDown();
        }
        else if (rightSide)
        {
            swipeRight();
        }
        else if (leftSide)
        {
            swipeLeft();
        }
        else
        {
            swipeUp();
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        if (upsideDown)
        {
            swipeUp();
        }
        else if (rightSide)
        {
            swipeLeft();
        }
        else if (leftSide)
        {
            swipeRight();
        }
        else
        {
            swipeDown();
        }
        break;
    }
}

private void swipeRight()
{
    if (right)
    {
        right = false;
        spin = true;
    }
    else if (left)
    {
        left = false;
    }
    else if (spin)
    {
        spin = false;
        left = true;
    }
    else if (up)
    {
        up = false;
        if (rightSide)
        {
            rightSide = false;
            upsideDown = true;
        }
        else if (leftSide)
        {
            leftSide = false;
        }
        else
        {
            rightSide = true;
        }
    }
    else if (down)
    {
        down = false;
        if (leftSide)
        {
            leftSide = false;
            upsideDown = true;
        }
        else if (rightSide)
        {
            rightSide = false;
        }
        else
        {
            leftSide = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        right = true;
    }
}

private void swipeUp()
{
    if (down)
    {
        down = false;
    }
    else if (up)
    {
        upsideDown = !upsideDown;
    }
    else if (upsideDown)
    {
        upsideDown = false;
        up = true;
    }
}
```